# Remove (not exact) duplicates of NSDictionaries from array

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, duplicates, nsdictionary

I have an NSMutableArray of many NSDictionaries that contain keys like "Title". In some cases there are duplicates of dictionaries with the same "Title" but differences in the other keys.
How can I remove the dictionaries that have the same "Title" key and leave only one in the array?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Sort the array using `NSSortDescriptor` on the key path 'title'. Next, loop over the array and build a new array:

```
NSString *lastTitle = nil;
NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSDictionary *d in array) {
    NSString *testTitle = [d objectForKey:@"title"];
    if (![testTitle isEqualToString:lastTitle]) {
        [result addObject:d];
        lastTitle = testTitle;
    }
}
```

Now `result` contains your filtered list.

It's important to sort the `array` first for this algorithm to work.